# How to organize python array with numpy zeros

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

Working on a simple SIR model.
I need to organize the values printed to the terminal to be organized in a fashion that my teacher can easily follow.
I was told to look into numpy.zeros, but I'm new to python and I need someone to help.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy
beta = 0.24
gamma = 0.142857
Tstart = 0
Tend = 151
r = 0
s = (306.8 * 10**6)
i = (22 * 10**6)

def compute_next_day(t,R,I,S):
    R[t] = gamma * I[t - 1] + R[t - 1]
    I[t] = (beta * I[t-1] * S[t-1] / (r+i+s)) - gamma * I[t-1] + I[t-1]
    S[t] = - (beta * I[t-1] * S[t-1] / (r+i+s)) + S[t-1]
    print S[t-1], I[t-1], R[t-1]


def compute_entire_period(Tstart, Tend, R, I, S):
    R[Tstart] = r
    I[Tstart] = i
    S[Tstart] = s
    for t in range(Tstart + 1, Tend):
        compute_next_day(t, R, I, S)


R = range(Tstart, Tend)
I = range(Tstart, Tend)
S = range(Tstart, Tend)

def graph(R, I, S):
    plt.plot(R)
    plt.plot(I)
    plt.plot(S)

plt.ylabel("Population")
plt.xlabel("Time")
plt.show()

(compute_entire_period(Tstart, Tend, R, I, S))
(graph(R,I,S))
```

The values printed to terminal are the S, I, R values...

[what currently appears on terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5Vkj.png)
[want to organize like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWAKb.png)

Comment: I find your question very unclear. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: show examples - what you get and what you expect.

Comment: added some pictures so you can see what I'm going for

Comment: You need to create a single numpy array from your lists (ranges), the pretty-printed version of that will look the way you want it to if you `print` it.

Comment: got it organized!   however, is there anyway to export the values to another document (such as a csv)?

Comment: The docs are your friend - https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: Welcome to SO:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

i don't have enough points to comment, so i'll "answer" to your question in commentary section, you can export the value to a csv like this :

```
import csv

a = range(2, 10)
with open("output.csv", "wb") as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerows(a)
```